# Nelmio Docs is returning 401 Undocumented

Tags: swagger, symfony4

When I try to execute API route without authentication, it returns correct message but there in the code I see `401 Undocumented`. Is this undocumented normal? where should I fix it. I have attached an image below:

### yaml file:

```
nelmio_api_doc:
    documentation:
        securityDefinitions:
            my_token:
                type: apiKey
                description: 'token'
                name: token_name
                in: header
```

[image: 401 Undocumented]

Comment: "Undocumented" means this response code isn't in the OpenAPI definition of this API. The OpenAPI definition is not necessarily expected to cover all possible HTTP response codes.

Comment: I have defined both 200 and 401 but for 401 its returning undefined.

Comment: Can you post your code/annotations where 200 and 401 are defined?

Comment: * @SWG\Response(
     *     response=200,
     *     description="Returns information...",
     *     @Model(type=Test::class),
     * )
     * @SWG\Response(
     *     response=401,
     *     description="Authentication Required",
     * )